Is there a way to set const value which can change due to its dependencies?
I am trying to set a const value using useState hook:
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(messages?.likes?.some((like)=>like.id === user.id))

Here, when messages change, liked value doesn't update. I know I can use useEffect hook, but is there a way to define the liked value without using useEffect hook?
EDIT: I need to use setState value, too, besides auto updated value.

Using a simple const and not a state?

I think I know what you think you’re saying, but since the useState’s param is initial state, no, because that wouldn’t make sense. The point of effects is to make those dependencies explicit and normalized. You may consider things like refactoring, custom hooks, etc

If answers here are not fully addressing the actual needs/use case then can you [edit] to clarify what the issue/problem is that you are trying to solve that you think avoiding the useEffect hook call fixes? You might be asking a bit of an XY problem.


Is there a way to set const value which can change due to its
dependencies?

Yes, use the useMemo hook. useMemo is basically useState + useEffect to keep it "synchronized". This is what is generally called derived state, and as such it is considered a bit of a React anti-pattern to store derived state in actual React state.
Example:
const isLiked = useMemo(
  () => !!messages?.likes?.some((like) => like.id === user.id),
  [messages, user]
);


I need to use setState value, too, besides auto updated value.

Based on the information provided if you need the local component state and are enqueueing state updates then you'll need to also use the useEffect hook if the goal is to keep the isLiked state synchronized to an external source, i.e. when messages.likes updates.

I have to use also setState, I mean setLiked  when I need to manually set its value.

@JeremyFc Ah, in that case you might just need the state and useEffect hook after all if you need to manually update it after mounting.

then I cannot accept your answer for this, thx for ur effort

@JeremyFc No worries, I answered your question as it was originally posted, and only tried to accommodate the later edit. It's likely to still be useful to some future reader perhaps. Cheers and good luck.


Here, when messages change, liked value doesn't update.

If the message changed, you should mount a new "Message" component (or how ever you call it).
If you give it a unique key (perhaps the message id) it should re-mount and the state would be re-calculated for that component.

If you want the value to update only when messages change, you can use useMemo to memoize the value. This will ensure that the liked value is recalculated only when messages are updated.
    const liked = useMemo(
      () => messages?.likes?.some((like) => like.id === user.id),
      [messages]
    );

